# Construction "Should + subj + verb + subj + will..."

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

There is the following sentence:

> "Should this bar deplete your weapons will automatically shut off..." [(c)](http://hosting.zaonce.net/elite/website/assets/English-PlayersGuidev1.04-INTERACTIVE.pdf)

What can I see here is that the sentence starts with question form and continues like conditional (frankly speaking I don't know how to call it correctly). 
I have never faced such a construction before and therefore I really eager to understand it in more details.

I would be really grateful to you if you at least can give me the right direction to google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand this correctly as a conditional. Subject-auxiliary inversion is an alternative to *if* for expressing the condition clause in a conditional construction:

> If this bar should deplete... → Should this bar deplete...
>   If I were to go... → Were I to go...
>   If I had gone ... → Had I gone...

At one time this construction was fairly common with all past-form auxiliaries, and those uses may still be encountered in some literary contexts

> Could I but see my native land again I would die happy.

But in present-day English it is usually found only with *were*, *had* and *should*; and even with those three it has an old-fashioned ring. As a learner you need to understand this construction, but it's not a very useful addition to your English toolkit, except possibly as a verbal trick to impress examiners.